# JavaScript not reading dynamic value {{*}}

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm trying to display a dynamic value (from Flask) in a specific color. If the value is "running" the button color should turn green, any other value should give a red. The coloring works fine if I write the value manually in the value field, but as soon as I put in the dynamic value {{status}}, JavaScript does not read it properly. What am I doing wrong? The page inspector is showing me the correct value though.

I've already tried with "|safe" along the value.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.status {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.status').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'running') {
            $(this).css('background-color','#4CAF50');
        } else {
    $(this).css('background-color','#e60c30');
    }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button class="status" value='{{status|safe}}'>Status</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what value is actually being rendered in browser?

Comment: Good point. By controlling again, I kind of get the following output:

value="running
"

It looks like there is some kind of a paragraph at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was not in this code directly, it had to do with the value I got from flask. My value had a "newline" /n at the end. So when I got rid of it, JavaScript could read it.